# Select upper and lower values and create a new column with random values

Tags: r, quantile

I have a data set with 30 rows and 2 columns. For example:

```
value <- c(305.19, 30.19, 126.97, 178.89, 640.01, 189.28, 15.92, 
           219.79, 178.89, 911.61, 178.89, 18.28, 305.19, 322.90,  
           126.97, 12.97, 178.89, 12.97, 322.90, 158.92, 322.90,
           219.79, 911.61, 219.79, 911.61, 325.90, 322.90, 911.61,  
           158.92, 322.78)

Date <- c("1997-05-01","1997-05-02","1997-05-03","1997-05-04","1997-05-05",
          "1997-05-06","1997-05-07","1997-05-08","1997-05-09","1997-05-10",
          "1997-05-11","1997-05-12","1997-05-13","1997-05-14","1997-05-15",
          "1997-05-16","1997-05-17","1997-05-18","1997-05-19","1997-05-20",
          "1997-05-21","1997-05-22","1997-05-23","1997-05-24","1997-05-25",
          "1997-05-26","1997-05-27","1997-05-28","1997-05-29","1997-05-30")

data <- data.frame(value, Date)
```

Using the `quantile` function, I can select values between the percentages 25%, 50%, 75%.

For example:

```
data$value <- data$value[data$value>=quantile(data$value)[4]]
newvalue <- data$value[data$value>=quantile(data$value)[4]]
data$value <- sample(newvalue, dim(data)[1], replace=T)
```

I would like to create a new column with random values only - lower 12.5% and upper 87.5%.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do

```
q1 <- quantile(data$value, probs = c(0.125, 0.875))
data$newValue <- sample(data$value[data$value > q1[1] & data$value < q1[2]], 
                             nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! It's possible to apply the same code to a set of more data? when put with values greater extremes r send me an error: Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid first argument

Comment: Another question, thus I was not taking the values between 12.5 and 87.5? I would like the extreme values, lower than 12.5% and upper than 87.5%. thanks so much

Comment: Could you post that as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

A dplyr solution

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% filter(ntile(value,n=8) %in% 2:7 == TRUE) %>%
  do(sample_n(.,30, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks shaya, I do not know much "dplyr" and did not understand why the numbers n=8, and 2:7?

Comment: It was just a short way of typing the middle six out of the eight octiles. If you wanted the upper and lower octiles, you would want `%in% c(1,8)`.